# drop table view, 1051 error

Tags: mysql

Um, I'm cleaning up old DBs through phpmyadmin, and during the process forgot to DROP a view before dropping the related tables. I'm getting the #1051 unknown table error of course -- but how do I drop the view now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using [DROP VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-view.html) syntax from mysql.

Comment: Simple solutions are always the best! Thanks! (note to self: must learn more SQL)